# Cassandra timeout during read query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (timeout while waiting for repair of inconsistent replica)

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

My application was working fine but today suddenly i keep getting this error from cassandra DB

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException: Cassandra timeout during read query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (timeout while waiting for repair of inconsistent replica)
```

i read few articles but all of them were about `(2 responses were required but only 1 replica responded)` which not the this exception is about.

can someone explain what could be the reason how if possible how to resolve it??

Answer (score 0):

So there are a few reasons that this message can suddenly start happening.

1. Querying from a new keyspace, which has the wrong data center name specified.  If the data center name is incorrect, then Cassandra won't know how to route the query.
2. Querying too many rows.  You haven't specified what your query is, which is important in diagnosing query timeouts.  If you're using `ALLOW FILTERING` and/or a `WHERE` clause that is too liberal or not based on a partition key, then this can happen as the data set grows.
3. Querying a large partition.  If your cluster has a "hot" partition or a partition that is subject to unbound growth, eventually that partition will get so big that it cannot be read.

I know this question is a bit old, but if you can edit your question with your query and table definition, that will help.